# Can "boilerplate" be used here?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have the following process implemented by a software component:

- a file is created by a designer
- the file is distributed to multiple systems, where the component runs
- the component creates a copy of the file and then it inserts data and charts
- the resulted file is sent for further processing

How should I call the file created by the designer? 
Is "boilerplate" a good term?

Comment: As an aside, it's not entirely clear that the 'file' and the 'component' are the same thing, in your second bullet point

Comment: @AndyT: please create an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Comment: @peterG: the component uses the file to generate other files; they are different things. How could I update the bullet point to emphasize this?

Comment: "Boilerplate" is sometimes used for this, but other terms, such as "template", are probably more apt.

Comment: @Dan I'd suggest you need a bullet point at the start to describe the relationship between the elements, maybe using less generic terms than 'component' too. I think one thing that led to my thinking that the 'file' and 'component' were the same entity, was the fact that the only thing you say is distributed is the file, leaving it unclear how the component reaches the target systems. Also - is the 'designer' part of the 'component', or does it refer to a human?  Aside from that, I'd suggest 'template' too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is:

- you have a file, which has certain sections in it, but not detailed information
- this file is copied into multiple places, and each copy has different detailed information added, each bit of information going into its relevant section
- the purpose of the file existing is so that all detailed information is presented in a common format

In my experience I would call this file a **[template](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/template)**:

> 7. *Computers.*
>
>    b. an electronic file with a predesigned, customized format and structure, as for a fax, letter, or expense report, ready to be filled in.

---

"[Boilerplate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/boilerplate)" is not the right term, it refers to repeated text (rather than a file), and there is no expectation of blank gaps to be filled in:

> 4. *Informal.* phrases or units of text used repeatedly, as in correspondence produced by a word-processing system.

Personally I've only ever come across "boilerplate" being used to describe email signatures.

Comment: it's definitely a template.  "Boilerplate" is reserved for a block of text which never changes.

Comment: @MaxWilliams - Good point. Do you think I should include the definition for "boilerplate" in my answer?

Comment: yes, I think that would help address the question.